# Putting a png background on h264 encoded mp4 video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to put a png file as a background to an h264 encoded mp4 video. I am just trying to replace the video's white background with a specific png background. They are both of the same size.

Can this be done using ffmpeg?

I have looked into using ffmpeg -filter_complex overlay but the background ended up covering the whole video. This is the command I tried:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:shortest=1’ output.mp4`

Comment: Welcome! Can you share the full ffmpeg command that you tried? What are you using to decide where to show the foreground and where to show the background? An alpha channel? A chroma or luma key?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply @MichaelLiebman. I used the command below.

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:shortest=1’ output.mp4`

I am not too sure I understand the second part of your question. I am just trying to replace the video's white background with a specific png background.

Comment: That means you are trying to do a luma key. There's a [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lumakey) for that.  I can't tell you specifically how to use it, but maybe that will give you more to search on in case someone else doesn't answer your question.